# Quasi-algebraically closed fields reference request

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am looking for a road to understanding what [quasi-algebraically closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-algebraically_closed_field#Ck_fields) are with the ultimate goal of understanding the paper by [Lang 1952](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969785).

My current background is the first 6 chapters from Milne's notes [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf). Currently I am also studying the 7th chapter from the same notes and the chapter on Brauer groups from [Milne's notes on class field theory](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf).

I am also familiar with Russian besides English. Apologizes if the question is not placed in an appropriate place, but I really seek some help here.

**EDIT:** At the advice given in a comment here, I deleted the post from here and moved the question to Stack Exchange, but it did not receive any answers there, so I undeleted this post.

Comment: This question is more appropriate in math.stackexchange but a good reference is the book by M. J. Greenberg, Forms of Higher Degree.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, but upon a google search, I did not find your title. Did you mean instead _Lectures on Forms in
Many Variables_ by Marvin Greenberg?

Comment: There is some material on $C_i$ fields in general, and some results on $C_1$ fields in particular, in Fried & Jarden's *Field Arithmetic* (the index isn't good, but it's mostly in chapter 21, "Problems of Arithmetical Geometry", at least in the 3rd edition of 2008).  Admittedly, there isn't much, but I'm not sure exactly what sort of things you're looking for.

Comment: @user223794 Yes, that's the one I mean. Must have confused it with something else.